# How to add thousands of items to a binded collection without locking GUI

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, observablecollection

I have a setup where potentially thousands of items (think 3000-5000) will be added to an `ObservableCollection` that is binded to some visual interface. Currently, the process of adding them is quite slow (approx. 4 seconds/1000 items), and of course the GUI is unresponsive during that time. What is a good method to handle moving that many items at once into a collection without worrying about the system locking up? I've looked at `DispatcherTimer` but I'm not sure if it will provide everything I need it to.

Another question - Is there something I can do to speed up the creation of these objects so that it doesn't take so long to add them to the collection? Currently I use them like so: `Collection.Add(new Item(<params>))` Would generating the items beforehand, in a background thread probably, decrease the time it takes to add them by a noticeable amount?

Edit: Virtualization is not possible. The requirements specify a `WrapPanel` look, so the display is actually a `ListBox` which has a templated ItemsPanel

Edit2: According to the stopwatch, the bottleneck is actually putting items into my `ObservableCollection`. I will try changing that collection type and doing my own notification to see if that speeds it up substantially.

Edit3: So the answer is in one place - I solved this issue (with help from below) by creating a class which inherits from `ObservableCollection`. This class did two things - expose a method to add collections at one time, and added the ability to suppress the `CollectionChanged` Event. With these changes the time it takes to add 3000 items is roughly .4 seconds (97% improvement). [This](http://peteohanlon.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/bulk-loading-in-observablecollection/) link details the implementation of these changes.

Comment: There are a few things you could do. One might be to create all of the objects before creating your ObservableCollection, that way, once you do create it, you can just initialize it with the collection of items you already have. Another option is using [ReactiveExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) which would allow you to "observe" your data source and add items to your ObservableCollection asynchronously.

Comment: Also, it's got to be your item creation that's the time sink, not the "add". So, can't you push the creation off onto another thread, collect them in some intermediate collection, and once they're created add them to the ObservableCollection on the GUI thread?

Comment: @Ryan These are some good points. I'll move the creation to the background and report my speed then.

Comment: there are also implementations of a virtualized WrapPanel out there if you wanted to add that as well

Comment: @steve89, just for the hell of it, is there any way you can populate the collection completely prior to creating to view? That way when the ItemsSource binding occurs, it happens to a populated collection. You can then see if it takes a while to display your view. I'm curious if it's the view that's causing the issue...trying to draw 1000 items every 4 seconds. If that's the case, virtualization is your friend

Comment: @Ryan There is a separate issue with displaying the view. My times are simply from filling the collection. There is an additional 3-4 second pause when drawing all the items for the first time (I put them in an expander, and that's the time it takes them to show when I expand it the first time)

Comment: Interesting...Are these huge objects? I have some sizable collections (~3000 items) where the model is about 10-15 primitive-type properties and 5-10 additional business object properties. These add to their respective collections very quickly.

Comment: @Ryan It's not abnormally complex. Just 7 primitives and a `DateTime` object. They represent files on a system, so there could be numerous depending on how the system is populated. I have a wrapper object which inherits from `ObservableCollection` and adds some functionality to watch the file system for updates. If needed, I can provide some of that code in my OP So you can better understand my setup.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to take your edit 3 and add it as an answer instead? It took me a while to find the information since I don't usually look for answers in the question. Also, I would like to upvote that solution!

Comment: I added my solution as an answer so people can find it easier. Funny to see this post still getting views and activity four years later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've said 1000, so I'll stick to that number just for instance.

IIRC, the observable collection has a small drawback - if you add the items one by one, it raises notifies once per each item. That means that you have 1000 notifications for 1000 of items and the UI thread will run at deadly speed just to keep up with redrawing the screen.

Do you need to redraw ASAP? Maybe you can batch the additions? Split the 1000 of items into a few packed of 100 items, or a little more packets of 50 or 20 items. Then, instead of putting all items one by one, put them in packets. But beware: you have to use some methods like AddRange implemented by the collection it self, not by LINQ, or else you will again have one-by-one insertion. If you find such method, it should cut the number of events significantly, because the collection should raise the Changed event only once per AddRange call.

If observable collection does not have AddRange, either use different collection, or write your own, just a wrapper will probably be sufficient. The goal is to NOT raise Changed event at every single Add(), but after a reasonable count of them, or - maybe just skip raising Changed when items are added and raise Changed at some regular time intervals? This would be beneficial especially, if your data "flows in" indefinitely at a constant rate.

Of course, at that number of items coming onto the screen, you may just as well be held at the rendering it self. If your ItemTemplates are complicated, a 1000 of objects times 1000 of instances of visual layers/properties may simply kill the user experience. Have you simplified the ItemTemplates to the bare minimum?

Last thing: consider using virtualizing StackPanels as the ItemPanels in your ItemsControl/ListBoxes. It can greatly reduce the memory footprint and the number of items drawn at a single point of time. This will not necessarily help in the number or events raised, but it may help greatly when you have complex item templates!

Edit: you are using ObservableCollection, so I've assumed WPF/Silverlight.. update the question if this is not correct

Comment: Yeah, OP would have to create their own collection since ObservableCollection does not implement AddRange. It is possible to use a CollectionView, IIRC, that would give the user control over when to "Refresh" the collection to the view.

Comment: I'm forced to use a WrapPanel, so virtualization isn't possible unless I use some codeproject attempts at VirtualizedWrapPanel (Which is actually on my list to try), so for now I am stuck with non-virtualized items. Because of this, my template is as simple as I could make it for these items.

Answer (score 8):

WPF `Binding` supports concurrency for this reason. Try setting [`Binding.IsAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync) to true. In addition.

- Don't use `ObservableCollection<T>`, it is slow for this because each time an item is added it raises events. Use something faster like `List<T>` and raise your property change notification *after* all your items are added.
- Pre-create your items in a background thread, then push them into your collection.
- Check other parts of code involved to see if there is bloat, and trim.

Comment: Even with that flag set I continue to get roughly the same amount of lag. ~12 seconds for while items are added to the collection

Comment: Good points here as well. I have a number of things to try now. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me! 

ItemsSource="{Binding collectionObject, IsAsync=True}">

Answer (score 6):

By request, here is how I solved this issue. I started by creating a class which inherits from `ObservableCollection`. This class did two things - expose a method to add entire collections at once, and added the ability to suppress the `CollectionChanged` Event. With these changes the time it takes to add 3000 items is roughly .4 seconds (97% improvement). [This](http://peteohanlon.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/bulk-loading-in-observablecollection/) link details the implementation of these changes.

Answer (score 4):

Another thing you can try: subclass ObservableCollection and make it support bulk loading (AddRange). Here is an article: 
[AddRange and ObservableCollection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nathannesbit/archive/2009/04/20/addrange-and-observablecollection.aspx)

Comment: This may end up being my route. I already subclassed `ObservableCollection`, but the base add (Which gets called 1000's of times) is eating up most of the time spent in the add loop.

Comment: You may also try calling AddRange from a background thread, and make your implementation of ObservableCollection dispatch OnCollectionChanged call to the UI thread. (AFAIR CollectionChanged event is NOT autoamtically dispatched to the UI thread by WPF binding)

Comment: Your comment pointed me in the right direction and let me find a solution that was fully implemented. View my edit for details. I still have to give credit to the person that brought up the idea first though.

Answer (score 0):

for second question
if in your GUI you are using WPF technologie, you can increase performance using  VirualizingStackPanel allowing you to create only visible items

Comment: I will edit my original post to explain why that's not possible.