# Adding bulk data to Observable Collection slows down the application performance

Tags: c#, wpf

I am plotting the graphs using WPF Toolkit and to bind the data to show up the plots i am using observable collection and adding the datapoints to the collection and giving this collection as itemsource for the plot.

My problem is when i am adding tooo many data points to my collection, or retriving the data points from the collection and try to show up the plot it is taking loooots of time to show up.

What can i do for this issue?

Please suggest me so that the performance can be improved.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Approximately how many data points are causing the issue? Also check if [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958375/how-to-add-thousands-of-items-to-a-binded-collection-without-locking-gui) or  [this](http://updatecontrols.net/doc/tips/common_mistakes_observablecollection) or [this](http://tliangnet.blogspot.in/2013/04/observablecollection-performance-issue.html) can help you.

Comment: I have more than 16thousand points approximately (which i have to read from csv file). I could able to read them all but while plotting only the performance issue is coming.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670577/observablecollection-doesnt-support-addrange-method-so-i-get-notified-for-each/45364074#45364074

Answer (score 0):

ObservableCollection notifies with every change and that means a lot of events so it affects performance. You can use a List instead of ObservableCollection but most people don't recommend it.

```
public class MainVm:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    List<Point> _points;
    public List<Point> Points
    {
        get { return _points; }
        set { _points = value; Notify("Points"); }
    }
    public void Notify(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

In this case you have to manually notify the view of changes made to the list. for example anywhere other than the constructor of your view model or view you have to do this:

```
Points.Add(new Point());
Points.Add(new Point());
Points.Add(new Point());
//View is not notified yet

var tmp = Points;
Points = null;//View is notified and cleared
Points = tmp;//View is notified and updated
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the subclass of ObservableCollection from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670577/observablecollection-doesnt-support-addrange-method-so-i-get-notified-for-each) post to add a .AddRange that batches updates and allows you to add items in bulk without triggering the update notification until the very end.

I've copied the code from the original post for completeness, but please upvote the linked post if you found it useful.

```
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class ObservableRangeCollection(Of T) : Inherits ObservableCollection(Of T) : Implements INotifyCollectionChanging(Of T)
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes a new instance of the System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of T) class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes a new instance of the System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of T) class that contains elements copied from the specified collection.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="collection">collection: The collection from which the elements are copied.</param>
    ''' <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">The collection parameter cannot be null.</exception>
    Public Sub New(ByVal collection As IEnumerable(Of T))
        MyBase.New(collection)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Adds the elements of the specified collection to the end of the ObservableCollection(Of T).
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub AddRange(ByVal collection As IEnumerable(Of T))
        Dim ce As New NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T)(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, collection)
        OnCollectionChanging(ce)
        If ce.Cancel Then Exit Sub

        Dim index = Items.Count - 1
        For Each i In collection
            Items.Add(i)
        Next

        OnCollectionChanged(New NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, collection, index))
    End Sub


    ''' <summary>
    ''' Inserts the collection at specified index.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub InsertRange(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal Collection As IEnumerable(Of T))
        Dim ce As New NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T)(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, Collection)
        OnCollectionChanging(ce)
        If ce.Cancel Then Exit Sub

        For Each i In Collection
            Items.Insert(index, i)
        Next

        OnCollectionChanged(New NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset))
    End Sub


    ''' <summary>
    ''' Removes the first occurence of each item in the specified collection from ObservableCollection(Of T).
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub RemoveRange(ByVal collection As IEnumerable(Of T))
        Dim ce As New NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T)(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, collection)
        OnCollectionChanging(ce)
        If ce.Cancel Then Exit Sub

        For Each i In collection
            Items.Remove(i)
        Next

        OnCollectionChanged(New NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset))
    End Sub



    ''' <summary>
    ''' Clears the current collection and replaces it with the specified item.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub Replace(ByVal item As T)
        ReplaceRange(New T() {item})
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Clears the current collection and replaces it with the specified collection.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub ReplaceRange(ByVal collection As IEnumerable(Of T))
        Dim ce As New NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T)(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, Items)
        OnCollectionChanging(ce)
        If ce.Cancel Then Exit Sub

        Items.Clear()
        For Each i In collection
            Items.Add(i)
        Next
        OnCollectionChanged(New NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset))
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub ClearItems()
        Dim e As New NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T)(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset, Items)
        OnCollectionChanging(e)

        If e.Cancel Then Exit Sub

        MyBase.ClearItems()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub InsertItem(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal item As T)
        Dim ce As New NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T)(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item)
        OnCollectionChanging(ce)
        If ce.Cancel Then Exit Sub

        MyBase.InsertItem(index, item)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub MoveItem(ByVal oldIndex As Integer, ByVal newIndex As Integer)
        Dim ce As New NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T)()
        OnCollectionChanging(ce)
        If ce.Cancel Then Exit Sub

        MyBase.MoveItem(oldIndex, newIndex)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub RemoveItem(ByVal index As Integer)
        Dim ce As New NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T)(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, Items(index))
        OnCollectionChanging(ce)
        If ce.Cancel Then Exit Sub

        MyBase.RemoveItem(index)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub SetItem(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal item As T)
        Dim ce As New NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T)(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, Items(index))
        OnCollectionChanging(ce)
        If ce.Cancel Then Exit Sub

        MyBase.SetItem(index, item)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnCollectionChanged(ByVal e As Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
        If e.NewItems IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each i As T In e.NewItems
                If TypeOf i Is INotifyPropertyChanged Then AddHandler DirectCast(i, INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged, AddressOf Item_PropertyChanged
            Next
        End If
        MyBase.OnCollectionChanged(e)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Item_PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As T, ByVal e As ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)
        OnCollectionChanged(New NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset, sender, IndexOf(sender)))
    End Sub

    Public Event CollectionChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T)) Implements INotifyCollectionChanging(Of T).CollectionChanging
    Protected Overridable Sub OnCollectionChanging(ByVal e As NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T))
        RaiseEvent CollectionChanging(Me, e)
    End Sub
End Class


Public Interface INotifyCollectionChanging(Of T)
    Event CollectionChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T))
End Interface

Public Class NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T) : Inherits CancelEventArgs

    Public Sub New()
        m_Action = NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move
        m_Items = New T() {}
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal action As NotifyCollectionChangedAction, ByVal item As T)
        m_Action = action
        m_Items = New T() {item}
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal action As NotifyCollectionChangedAction, ByVal items As IEnumerable(Of T))
        m_Action = action
        m_Items = items
    End Sub

    Private m_Action As NotifyCollectionChangedAction
    Public ReadOnly Property Action() As NotifyCollectionChangedAction
        Get
            Return m_Action
        End Get
    End Property

    Private m_Items As IList
    Public ReadOnly Property Items() As IEnumerable(Of T)
        Get
            Return m_Items
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: I implemented the way suggested above i.e, inherted a class from Observable collection and added the data using AddRange function. But still i dont find a major difference in the performance. I am using WPF toolkit for plotting. Is this matters for performance?? Id so, please suggest me the ways to improve the performance. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try using virtuallization with:

```
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll = "True"  
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing = "True"  
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode = "Standard"
```

That way WPF will only render what you can see in a scroll viewer.
You should test if that gives you a better performance.